# Why did I have to change the type of a the value of a map from & to (int*)&

Tags: c++, dictionary, constants

I have the function  `getElement` that returns a pointer to a value of a map.

```
 int * getElement(const int &key) const {
        return (int*)&m.find(key)->second;
    }
```

If I use for instance `return &m.find(key)->second` it creates a compilation error:

> In member function 'int* A::getElement(const int&) const': 12:30:
>   error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

- Why do I have to change `&m.find(key)->second` to `(int*)&m.find(key)->second` in order for the code to compile correctly?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class A {
    public:
    void addElement(const int &key, const int &value) {
         m.emplace(key,value);
    }
    int * getElement(const int &key) const {
        return (int*)&m.find(key)->second;
    }
    private:
    std::map<int,int> m;

};


int main()
{
  A a;
  int value = 1;
  int key = 1;
  a.addElement(key,value);
  int * x = a.getElement(1);
  std::cout << *x << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why do I have to change `&m.find(key)->second` to `(int*)&m.find(key)->second`

You don’t. In fact, doing so potentially creates an error. Instead, remove the `const` qualifier on your member function if you really want to modify the map values. Or return a `const int*` instead of an `int*` from the function.

To clarify, when you specify a member function as being `const`, then the `this` pointer inside that function becomes a pointer to a `const` instance of your class. This, in turn, makes its data members `const`, transitively.

As a consequence, your `std::map<int, int>` becomes a `std::map<int, int> const` inside your `getElement` function. Furthermore, [`std::map::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) has an overload for `const` maps that returns a `const_iterator` — hence the `const int*`.

In fact, be careful: `std::map::iterator` isn’t necessarily `T*`. So you shouldn’t return `int*` or `const int*` — you should return `std::map<int, int>::iterator` (or `…::const_iterator`).

Answer (score 1):

this membre fonction

```
int * getElement(const int &key) const
```

is constant so you can access all data membre as constant

and `int*` is different from `const int*`